# Adding multiple categories to ActionScript variables

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4

I am a designer trying to modify some ActionScript for a web project. When defining the variables, I would like for some of them to have multiple parameters/categories (I apologize for my lack of vocabulary).

For example...

```
var Projects= [
{myName:"Example1",myType:"OldProject",myCopy:"Coming soon."}    
// etc

];
```

How can I include multiple parameters so, for example, `myType` could be set to `OldProject` and `2005Project` at the same time?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `myType` parameter to be an array of strings instead of just one.

then you can access them in a loop to find all of the `types` values.

something like this:

```
var Projects= [
{myName:"Example1",types:["OldProject", "2005Project"],myCopy:"Coming soon."}
];

for (int i = 0; i < Projects[0].types.length; i++) {
    // access them with Projects[0].types[i]
}
```

Comment: That should be an array initializer: `types:["OldProject", "2005Project"]` (square brackets).

Answer (score 0):

Some of the options include:

```
//1. JSON like object option
var projects:Object = {myName:"Example1",myType:"OldProject",myCopy:"Coming soon."};
trace(projects.myName + projects.myType + "etc..."); //Access it

//2. Dicitonary option
import flash.utils.Dictionary;
var d:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
d["myName"] = "Example1"; //Set values like this
trace(d["myName"]); //Access them like this
```

There's also an associative array, a custom class, etc..., but I would recommend option 1 for you especially if you are more designer than programmer.

If you wanted to "Stack properties you can set myType to an array or another object, something like:

```
obj.myType = {one:"OldProject", two: "2005Project"};
trace(obj.myType.one + obj.myType.two);
```

or

```
obj.myType = new Array();
obj.myType[0] = "OldProject";
obj.myType[1] = "2005Project";
trace(obj.myType[0], obj.myType[1]); //Access them
```

Comment: I think you might just have pulled my answer there :)

Comment: lol, I re-read the OP and forgot to include the "stacking" thing. I'll +1 you since you included that part before I did.